# printing answer up to 9 digits on division in java

Tags: java

How do we print division up to 9 digits?

If variable `num` holds 2 and variable `den` holds 4, then I need to print `0.500000000`

```
double ans=(double)(num)/(double)(den);
System.out.println(ans);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.9f", ans));
```

Like in C, the `%f` tell the format to expect a float/double value, and the `.9` instructs it to print 9 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: You can also directly use `System.out.printf("%.9f", ans);`

Comment: You might want to add `%n` for a new line.